# Code highlighting tensorflow with python

Tags: feature-request

Tensorflow, the popular machine learning library ([2K questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow)), is currently only available in python. Can we associate the code highlighting with the [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) tag to match that of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)?